# Write to file and print to screen out of step with each other

Tags: python

I have a problem with writing to file.
What seems to happen is that a program prints numbers to screen in the order 0,1,2,3 (zeroth, first, second, third) but writes to file in the order -1, 0, 1, 2. Even when the print to screen command follows the write to file command.
Sample code follows. Any ideas how to make it write to file in order 0,1,2,3?

Many thanks - Scriptham.

```
import random
import time

ln = 4
mins = 10
j = 0
n_sensor = 0
temp_c = 0
data_file = "/home/pi/laboratory/test.csv"

def read_temp():
    temp_c = 100 * random.random()
    return str("%.3f"% temp_c)


for j in range (1,mins):
    f = open(data_file,'a')
    f.write("\n" + str(j))
    f.close
    for n_sensor in range (0,ln):
        #device_file_1 =
        print("A " + str(n_sensor))
        x = read_temp()
        f = open(data_file, 'a')
        f.write("," + x)
        f.close
        print("OP temp_c = ", x)
        #time.sleep(0.5)
    time.sleep(10) #normally would be 59.5 or 60 or similar

quit()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make sure the file is always closed, you should use the `with` statement.
For example:

```
with open(data_file, 'a') as f:
    f.write("\n" + str(j))
```

This will close the file, even if an exception happens during the `write`.

Alternatively, you need to use something like:

```
f = open(data_file, 'a')
try:
    f.write("\n" + str(j))
finally:
    f.close()
```

Comment: Thankyou both for your advice, the program now works correctly. Problem solved. ScriptHam

Comment: If your question has been answered, please mark one of the solutions as correct.

Comment: Thanks skyhisi. I'm not sure how to mark things as correct. For information parts of both answers were used to solve the problem.

Comment: You should be able to click a green tick icon below the answer up/down buttons next to the question. Take a look at the Tour page: https://stackoverflow.com/tour

Answer (score 4):

The problem is most likely that you're opening the output file dozens of times, but never closing it.

You should do `f = open(data_file,'a')` *before* the loop and only *once*. Then when everything's done, *call* `f.close()` (`f.close` is not the same as `f.close()`!).